# Parameters are not passing anything or passing null

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Payments Controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @orders = Order.where(user_id: @user.email)
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    price = @product.avgprice.to_i*100
    @user = current_user
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: price,
        currency: "gbp",
        source: token,
        description: params[:stripeEmail],
        reciept_email: @user.email
      )

      if charge.paid
        Order.create(product_id: @product.id, user_id: @user.email, total: price)
      end
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      #The card has been declined
      body = e.json_body
      err = body[:error]
      flash[:error] = "Unfortunately, there was an error processing your payment: #{err[:message]}"
    end
    redirect_to(payments_show_path)
  end
end
```

_stripe_checkout_button.html:

```
<%price = @product.avgprice.to_i * 100%>
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"

    data-amount="<%=price%>"
    data-name= "<%=@product.name%>"
    data-description="<%=@product.description%>"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="gbp">

  </script>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id)%>
</form>
```

Show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(url: '/payments/create') do |form| %>
<%= render partial: 'shared/stripe_checkout_button'%>
<% end %>
```

I expected the <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id)%> to pass the product id to the payment controller at `@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])`. But it does not seem to be working. Any help? An error I am getting from this is:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PaymentsController#create
Couldn't find Product without an ID

Comment: why are there apostrophes around that line? that way rails thinks this line is a text, try removing them. (and another thing, rails will ALLWAYS think that text surrounded by apostrophes is a string, and won't evaluate the value of the variables. If you need to evaluate some value you need to use quotation marks! (use "" instead of '', unless you need text)

Comment: I was trying many different things to see if any would pass something through the param. The message I am left with everytime is still: Couldn't find Product without an ID. No matter the format of the hidden field tag or whether it is in apostrophes. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: try passing the parameter to your partial: <%= render partial: 'shared/stripe_checkout_button, locals: {product: @product}'%>. And then in the partial use product without the @ to access the var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the solution me and my mentor found was to change the value to a non dynamic value. I did not understand why this worked but it did:

Thanks for everyone that helped on the way